# Exists some Ubuntu 16.04 known bugs/issues site?

Tags: 16.04, bug-reporting

Is there some usefull web site where known bugs/issues with Ubuntu 16.04 and workarounds are collected.

Answer (score 3):

yes! here is Ubuntu's official bug tracking website

https://bugs.launchpad.net/